# Migrating ansible version 1.5.4 to latest ansible version

Tags: ansible

I have been using ansible 1.5.4 for 8 month. Yesterday I found that   login_port of mysql_repilcation module is not supported in 1.5.4 version.

It is a bug in that version, but they supported in latest version (>= 1.8 I think). But I already have more than 50 ansible script running in 1.5.4
which has been used in production side

What is the best possible scenario:

1. If I move 1.5.4 to latest version , will it impact on any existing 
   ansible script
2. Is it possible to achieve the desire outout by shell command.

I am stuck in the middle of ocean. please help me to out of this 
problem

Answer (score 1):

> 1. If I move 1.5.4 to latest version , will it impact on any existing 
>      ansible script

This highly depends on your playbook/roles, but I'm pretty sure it won't just work without changes. For example I read many times now that users have problems with `sudo` on role level:

```
- roles:
   - role: whatever
     sudo: yes
```

That was broken in 1.9.1. Officially it is fixed but I have read users have still problems. Generally sudo has been replaced with [become](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html). Even though the documentation [claims](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#sudo-and-su-still-work) sudo is still supported, it clearly isn't completely.

Another change I remember was related to ssh transport but you should only stumble about this issue if you reboot your host during play with Ansible.

I think the sudo/become change was the biggest one. If you want to avoid the hassle and do not necessarily need the very recent version you might just upgrade to a version before 1.9 and will have better chances of getting through without changes.

If you have the time though, I recommend you make your play compatible with the recent version. The Ansible 2.0 release is ahead and will introduce many new very useful features.

> 2. Is it possible to achieve the desire outout by shell command.

You mean to automatically convert your playbook/roles? No, not unless you find out exactly about the problems and write that script yourself. :)

> I am stuck in the middle of ocean. please help me to out of this problem

Generally you should test every new version of Ansible on a testing/staging environment first. If you do not have testing hosts you can set up local VM's. There you can test and fix your play.

Answer (score 0):

Since login_port of mysql_repilcation module is not supported in ansible 1.7 version. I found a way to achieve the result.

```
-  name: "stop slaves of existing database server"
   shell: >
      mysql -uroot -p{{ mysql_exist_slave_database_password }} \
        -P{{ default_port }} -h{{ default_host }}  -e "stop slave" -s


- name: "Retrieve the Position and binary file number using slave 
         status"
  shell: >
       mysql -uroot -p{{ mysql_exist_slave_database_password }} \
            -P{{ default_port }} -h{{ default_host }}  -e "show slave 
            status\G" -s
  register: output



- name: "start slaves of existing database server"
 shell: >
        mysql -uroot -p{{ mysql_exist_slave_database_password }} -P{{    
        default_port }} -h{{ default_host }}  -e "start slave" -s
```